# Crosstab normalize in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, crosstab

df
[image]

```
pd.crosstab(df.Sex ,[df.Nationality,df.Handedness],margins =True,margins_name = 'Total')
```

is computing simple cross tabulation
[image]
but when i a trying to normalize it is showing error

```
pd.crosstab(df.Sex ,[df.Nationality,df.Handedness],margins =True,margins_name = 'Total',normalize = True)
```

cause margin name is not found in table .
[image]

how can i normalize crosstab ?

Comment: This is a known bug (which doesn't allow margins and normalize to be used together) which is fixed here. https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/27661.

Comment: working fine in this case  `pd.crosstab(df.Nationality,df.Sex,normalize = 'index',margins = True)`  @ThirupathiThangavel